Read a S2P file with Julia
I'd like to read a S2P file (containing a frequency response) with Julia.
What is the best way to do it? Is there an equivalent of "scikit-rf" (Python) in Julia?
I saw: SParameters and Touchstone on the Internet but it doesn't work for me. Maybe the packages are no longer usable?
Thanks in advance

Those packages, at least Touchstone.jl, haven't been updated in years, so it is possible they are no longer supported. It may be helpful to open an issue on their source. In the meantime, I would recommend Marconi.jl , found here: https://docs.juliahub.com/Marconi/MZqH0/0.1.0/ . It even specifically aims to "give similar functionality as the wonderful scikit-rf library in pure Julia."
